# Why does 'Return' check only the first element in a list?

Tags: python

A very simple sample of code to sort out a difficulty with 'Return'. 
Let's assume I have a list, and the purpose is to verify whether an element is within the list.

```
lst = [1, 2, 10, 50, 100, 500]
```

A function can be:

```
def(number, x):   #The first parameter stands for the number I want to search. 
  for i in range(0, len(x), 1):
        if (x[i] == number):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

What do I not know/understand about the 'return' keyword?

If I substitute '`number`' with 2, it will return False. Basically, can someone explain why does this function check only the first element in the list, please?

Comment: `return` causes the function to end and gives back the given value. But in your case, you do not want the function to end, because you still have to go through the remainder of the elements in the list. Instead, you should `return False` only after you've gone through every element and not found it in the list.

Comment: simply use `return number in x`

Answer (score 2):

When the function returns, it stops executing any code and gives back the value returned. This causes the loop to only go through the first item in the list, because the function returns no matter what. Therefore, you should only return after the loop is complete:

```
def(number, x):
    for i in range(0, len(x), 1):
        if (x[i] == number):
            return True
    return False
```

However, I'd recommend using `in` instead:

```
>>> 2 in [1, 2, 10, 50, 100, 500]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over x, you don't need range:

```
def check(number, x):  #The first parameter stands for the number I want to search.
    for i in x:
        if i == number:
            return True      
    return False # outside the loop, will return False if the number is not equal to any number in x
```

Or simple use in:

```
In [4]: lst = [1, 2, 10, 50, 100, 500]

In [5]:  2 in lst
Out[5]: True

def check(number, x):  #The first parameter stands for the number I want to search.
    return number in x
In [23]: check(2,lst)
Out[23]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def(number, x):
  for i in range(0, len(x), 1):
    if (x[i] == number):
        return True
  return False
```

be careful, `return` stops and leaves the whole function